# Compare Count From Outer SELECT in a Nested SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL Query,

```
select * from (select * from .......) as a
where 1 = case when CountOfInnerSelect = 1 Then 1 ELSE ............
```

Is it possible I can get Count of inner select inside the outer SELECT?

Comment: You can select the count from subquery then use it. `SELECT a.Cnt, ... FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) as Cnt FROM ... WHERE ...) as a WHERE 1 = a.Cnt...` You can do it without selecting it in your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE Clause` does not make much sense as it is applied like a filter here. (ie; similar to `WHERE myCount = 1`)

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT c1,c2,c3,..,Cn,COUNT(*) AS myCount
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY c1,c2,c3,..,Cn
) A
WHERE 1 = CASE myCount WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE... END
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes :

```
select * from (select count(0) as cnt from .......) as a
where 1 = case when a.cnt = 1 Then 1 ELSE ............
```

Comment: I need to select my coulmns in the inner select as well.